# Firebase authentication: is there a way to set multiple phone numbers for a single user account?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase support a single user with multiple phone numbers?

We are building a system where the admin of a group may add users to a group by simply adding their phone number(s) *(a user may have multiple numbers)*. And we're considering using Firebase authentication.

User is *required* to add their email, password, phone numbers when signing up on the system. This basically grants the user access to the groups where their phone number is listed whenever they login.

In a case where a user has two phone numbers A & B, he may signup for **Group1** with **phone A**, and signup for **Group2** with **phone B**. Firebase allows for Phone Authentication, which also verifies that this user is the true owner of the phone number and thus we can grant them access to their relevant subscribed groups.

We'd like the user to login using their email/pass or any of their phone numbers and still be able to see all their subscribed to groups. So on our above example user should see **Group1** and **Group2** irrelevant to whether they signed in with their **email/pass**, **phone A** or **phone B**.

This requires that user profile should have both (or more!) phone numbers, but reading through Firebase docs, we couldn't see relevant information for having multiple phone numbers for a single user. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Thanks @JinLiu, that's how we originally thought of to solve the problem. Though, the admin adding phone numbers to a group doesn't 'create user', meaning in most cases the user wouldn't have been created yet to add their userID to a group.