# Can a single user have multiple phone numbers linked to his account in Firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) section in Firebase documentation shows how to link a single account to multiple auth providers. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future. But it doesn't say anything about linking two emails or two phone numbers to the same account. So, I was asking if it was possible to link multiple credentials of the same auth providers to a single account.

A similar question has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49190932/12357035), but it has no answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way you can merge two Firebase accounts created with two different phone numbers into a single one.

On the other hand, when it comes to authentication with email and password, by default, you can use one account per email address. This is done to prevent users from creating multiple accounts using the same email address with different authentication providers. However, this can be changed in the Firebase console, in the "Sign-in method" tab, inside the Authentication section.

Comment: What about linking a second phone number to existing account, so that, in future user can use either of the phone numbers to login.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. The only option that you have is to [enroll](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/MultiFactor#enroll(com.google.firebase.auth.MultiFactorAssertion,%20java.lang.String)) a phone number as a second factor.

Comment: Hey Sourav! Can I help you with other information?

Comment: No, I was just waiting for a day before I accepting any answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @Alex, can you please just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70141326/12357035) question I posted a while ago and I didn't got any convincing answers still.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.